# ftp kafka connector - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-kafka, ftp, apache-kafka-connect

While running the connectors i am getting this below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/metrics/Metrics;)V
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectMetrics.<init>(ConnectMetrics.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:83)
```

My reference link https://github.com/Eneco/kafka-connect-ftp

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong version of the Kafka JAR in the classpath at runtime.

Comment: I am having the latest version of kafka jar

Comment: Any other specified solution for this error?

Comment: You need to verify the kafka-client jar version, i got the same error when trying to update from 0.10.2.0 to 1.0.0

Comment: You might have multiple versions of Kafka jar in your classpath.